# Can't ssh to server after Debian upgrade to Buster without previous login from "trusted machine"

Tags: debian, ssh, sshd

I have just upgraded my Debian server from Stretch (stable) to Buster (testing).

One strange thing I can't seem to resolve:

```
$ ssh vlastimil@192.168.0.102 -p [censored] -o ConnectTimeout=5 -i /home/vlastimil/.ssh/id_rsa -vvv
```

results in:

```
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "192.168.0.102" port [censored]
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.0.102 [192.168.0.102] port [censored].
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: connect to address 192.168.0.102 port [censored]: Connection refused
```

```
ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.102 port [censored]: Connection refused
```

---

However, if I log in as that user locally (I can even log off then, it just needs one login), it does work.

I was able to log in as root. However, only from the one machine, in spite of having public key exchanged.

Further, only one root login from that one machine needed, and then it is possible to log in as root from the other machine.

Could anyone elaborate as to, how do I debug this issue?

---

Server's config:

```
# grep -v '#' /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Port [censored]
Protocol 2
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO
LoginGraceTime 120
StrictModes yes
HostbasedAuthentication no
IgnoreRhosts yes
PermitEmptyPasswords no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
X11Forwarding yes
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog no
Banner none
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 4096
Ciphers chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com
MACs hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com
KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
FingerprintHash sha512
Match Address 192.168.0.*
    PermitRootLogin yes
Match all
    PermitRootLogin no
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to [telcoM](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/258991/telcom)'s [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/478434/126755) about a Hardware RNG I did an `apt search` and found the package `rng-tools5` and installed it:

```
sudo apt-get install rng-tools5
```

This resolved the issue on my Intel NUC.

---

Editor's note: My issue on Dell PowerEdge T20 with Xeon CPU was also resolved with this.

Additional notes:

- After installation of the package, please do check if there is a random source with:

  ```
  rngd -v
  ```

  In my case, there is no TPM device, but the CPU has `rdrand` capability:

  > ```
  > Unable to open file: /dev/tpm0
  > Available entropy sources:
  >     DRNG
  > ```

Answer (score 6):

`connection refused` suggests that `sshd` is not running.

It might be just a matter of time: when the login prompt appears on the console, it does not guarantee that all the system services have completed startup yet.

`sshd` might be also be stuck waiting on `/dev/[u]random`, especially if the system is located in a network segment with very little network traffic. In this case, the system has very few sources of true randomness available and has difficulties gathering up enough truly random bits for initially seeding the kernel's random number generator. Logging onto the system console will provide some randomness in the form of the lowest bits of keyboard interrupt call times. If the system has some form of hardware RNG, enabling it might fix this problem.

To diagnose, just type a few lines of nonsense to the console login prompt without actually logging in. If `sshd` responds normally after that, the kernel was probably starved of randomness and unable to seed the kernel RNG, and that caused the startup of `sshd` to be delayed.

Or it might be some sort of `systemd` dependency bug that only allows `sshd` to start up when the login-related processes get started first. That would be one of the reasons why Debian Buster is still the `testing` distribution: if this turns out to be the cause, please send a bug report.

Answer (score 2):

The package haveged solved the problem.

The thread:
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=912087